# Automatically switch on speakers when there are Alsa clients

Tags: linux, audio, raspberry-pi, speakers, alsa

I want to connect a relay to one of the GPIOs of my Raspberry Pi.  This relay supplies power to the speakers.

I would like my speakers to be on only when there is sound activity.

I am looking for some mechanism to automatically switch the speakers on upon the first client connection, and off after the disconnection of the last client.  A delay before unplugging the speakers could help to lengthen their life, but it is not crucial.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this by means of inotifywait on the /dev/snd/* relevant device.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=524917#p524917